# Using list of PIN14 numbers and addresses to replace addresses in ArcMap attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, address, parcel

In my attribute table I have a PINs field and an Address field (along with other zoning information) that I want to replace with correct addresses.

Is there a way I can have ArcMap go through and replace all the addresses with the new ones so long as they match an existing pin and if there is no match then have it remove the current address? I assume there is some simple field calculator expression for this.

Comment: What have you tried? See examples [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0)

Comment: The field calculator cannot delete records. You are describing at least 2 steps. The best way to do this depends on what you mean by address: is it one big field or lots of parts, each a field?

Comment: @danak I don't have the new info yet but I believe the entire address is in one field.

Answer (score 1):

From the address file, do a Join by Attribute on PIN field to the PIN table, keeping all records. The addresses that do not have a matching PIN will have null values in all the PIN table part of the record (the last fields). To be safe, Select by Attribute on the PIN table's ObjectID/OID field is null. (This ensures that there really is no match because ObjectId/OID can never be null in the original table).  Then back those selected records up and delete them; with a little research or editing, some might be matched to the PIN table.

In an edit session, clear the previous selection and field calculate the address table address field to the PIN table address field. Then take off the join.

If there had been many fields to update, the workflow might involved deleting everything first and appending the good data back in with a field map.